# Is clone the only way to get contents of a Mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial

I am trying to get the sources for Netbeans IDE by running:

hg clone http://hg.netbeans.org/main/

However, this seems to be taking forever, and it does not give me any kind of status which tells me the percent of download that's complete. If a lose my internet connection, I have to start all over again.

I realize that Mercurial is a distributed source control system, and perhaps the 'clone' command is taking this long because it is getting the entire history of all the files (is this correct?)

When we get sources from CVS we usually get the source without the entire history. Is it possible to do something like this with Mercurial?

Comment: I used to be a fan of Mercurial, but after waiting for several hours for history to get downloaded I am beginning to change my mind. Offline operation is a good goal, but I don't need years of history at this cost most of the time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be a [`clone -verbose`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/bts/msg5141) would give you more details about what goes wrong ?

```
C:\netbeans-src>hg clone --verbose http://hg.netbeans.org/main
destination directory: main
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
```

If there is no errors, you may consider a [**Shallow clone**](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/index.cgi/ShallowClone) to not pull the entire history from a server, but only a subset starting at a given revision.
As mentioned by [Ry4an](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8992/ry4an), this is an "alpha extension", and not yet a perennial solution.

Comment: Mercurial doesn't yet have shallow clones and suggesting someone use an alpha extension for them isn't sound advice.

Answer (score 7):

Mercurial's [hgweb](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/index.cgi/PublishingRepositories) can be [configured to allow download of snapshots](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/index.cgi/PublishingRepositories#head-8a47f2fb27fd2b2552d960884ebb9f57c332eb96), e.g.,

> Make sure that your repository's .hg/hgrc file (or the /home/user/.hgrc file) contains the allow_archive setting:
>
> [web]
> allow_archive = gz, zip, bz2
>
> This example illustrates how gzip, zip and bzip2 archive formats can be supported. As a result, links should appear in the Web interface corresponding to these archive types.

However, it does not look like the repository you are trying to download allows this mode of operation.  You might request that they add it.